# py2app No such file or directory: .... python3.9/site-packages/zmq/.dylibs'

Tags: python, macos, py2app

Trying to create a build with py2app, and it works perfectly in alias mode after running

`python setup.py py2app -A`

However, when I run it without the flag to bundle everything in, I get an error.

`python setup.py py2app`

results in an error

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Kenan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/.dylibs'
```

What is this file it's looking for & how would I solve this error?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have actually solved the problem by copying .dylib folder into the path.
In may case,

> /Users/Kenan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/

path is actually exists but doesnt have a folder `.dylib`.

I have another python folder and it also does zmq module in site-packages. And luckily it has .dylib folder. So I just copied to the folder and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

*conda remove zeromq*

*conda install zeromq*